# An infinite sum resembling Erdős–Borwein constant

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to express the following infinite sum in terms of any special function 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^n-1},\qquad x\in(0,1)$$

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{n}}{2^{n}-1}=\sum_{n\geq1}x^{n}\frac{\frac{1}{2^{n}}}{1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}}=-\sum_{n\geq1}x^{n}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{2^{kn}}=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{x}{2^{k}}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2^{k}}}
 $$ $$=x\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{2^{k}-x}$$ and recalling the definition of the $q$-digamma function $$\psi_{q}\left(z\right)=-\log\left(1-q\right)+\log\left(q\right)\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{q^{n+z}}{1-q^{n+z}}$$ we get $$\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{2^{k}-x}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\psi_{1/2}\left(1-\log_{2}\left(x\right)\right)}{x\log\left(2\right)}$$ so $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{n}}{2^{n}-1}=1-\frac{\psi_{1/2}\left(1-\log_{2}\left(x\right)\right)}{\log\left(2\right)}.$$
 We can use the same ideas to get that in general holds $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{n}}{a^{n}-1}=\frac{\log\left(\frac{a}{a-1}\right)-\psi_{1/a}\left(1-\log_{a}\left(x\right)\right)}{\log\left(a\right)}.
 $$ with $a>1$ and $x\in(0,1]$.